# Melhoria de inserção de imagens no bd

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-eloquent

Como seria uma forma de minimizar esse código de inserção de imagens no banco de dados?

```
//  controller/GaleriasController.php

public function addGaleria {
  $galeria = new Galeria;
  $galeria->descricao = "galeria 1";
  $galeria->img1 = Input::file('img1');
  $name = Input::file('img1')->getClientOriginalName(); 
  Input::file('img1')->move('/arquivos', $name);

  $galeria->img2 = Input::file('img2');
  $name = Input::file('img2')->getClientOriginalName(); 
  Input::file('img2')->move('/arquivos', $name);

  $galeria->img3 = Input::file('img3');
  $name = Input::file('img3')->getClientOriginalName(); 
  Input::file('img3')->move('/arquivos', $name);
  $galeria->save();
}
```

Tá salvando a imagem no banco de dados e no diretório corretamente, só que se eu tivesse 10 tabelas com 10 campos de imagens cada uma...

Eu já tentei criar um array de inserção só que não consegui :(

Comment: você está salvando imagens no banco de dados, ou só a descrição da imagem? Armazenar imagens no banco de dados, em geral, _não é uma boa opção_

Comment: eu salvo a imagem no diretorio e o nome da imagem no bd, to ate pensando em renomear as imagens com o nome temporario que o laravel cria para evitar imagens com mesmo nome...

Comment: "Melhoria" soa melhor que "Melhoramento". Eu acho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha sugestão para melhorar é assim:

```
//  controller/GaleriasController.php

public function addGaleria
{
  $galeria = new Galeria;
  $galeria->descricao = "galeria 1";
  $max = 3;   // quantidade de imagens

  for ($n = 1; $n <= $max; $n++)
  {
    $img = 'img' . $n;
    $galeria->$img = Input::file($img);
    $name = Input::file($img)->getClientOriginalName(); 
    Input::file($img)->move('/arquivos', $name);
  }

  $galeria->save();
}
```

Comment: uma coisa que me fez pensar foi a seguinte: será que ao executar o for isso não iria acabar inserindo apenas o ultimo looping (img3)... pois o método save() é executado só apos o for

Comment: Não. O `save` deve ficar depois do *loop* mesmo, e irá salvar de uma vez todos os campos da nova Galeria. Exatamente como já acontece no seu código que consta na pergunta.

Comment: vou testar no meu not quando chegar em casa.. tomara que dê certo .... e hoje eu ainda tenho que inserir os filtros antes desse controller... amanhã posto o resultado J. Bruni

Comment: Testado e aprovado...